# FlexRay - Пропавшие PDU

Tags: многопоточность, windows-7, железо, can

Наша программа представляет собой приложение C # / .NET, которое использует vxlapi_NET.dll от Vector для связи с шиной FlexRay. Для этого мы сначала читаем содержимое файла FIBEX и настраиваем соответствующие свойства из класса xl_fr_cluster_configuration DLL, а затем используем функции XLDriver для подключения к шине. Код для настройки кластера выглядит примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текущая аппаратная настройка состоит из TTXConnexion и Vector VN7600 Box, которые подключены через USB к обычному ПК с Win7. Аппаратное обеспечение сконфигурировано для циклической отправки 6 разных PDU в статическом сегменте. Мы знаем идентификаторы и содержимое этих PDU, и, например, CANalyzer принимает и обрабатывает их правильно.

Однако в нашем программном обеспечении поступает только один из 6 ожидаемых PDU, и он не содержит ожидаемых нами значений. Vector Support говорит, что проблема с DLL часто связана с синхронизацией в потоке RX. Наш поток получения аналогичен примеру приложения Vector:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что может вызывать эти TIMING проблемы и что может вызывать эти проблемы?

Comment: Разные причины могут быть, но все наши предположения будут гаданием на салфетке.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста примеры возможных причин. Где начинать искать решение этой проблеммы?